# Can Fen earn more than one charge in a single turn?

Tags: steamworld-heist

The description for Fen’s Lightning Coil ability states:

> When Fen delivers a fatal blow to an enemy, gain an energy charge.

**If Fen defeats multiple enemies in a single turn, will he get multiple charges?**

Methods of defeating multiple enemies in one turn include:

- Using an explosive weapon
- Shooting an explosive barrel
- Using a handgun that can fire multiple times
- Using equipment that counts as a free action

Answer (score 1):

Simultaneous kills grant one charge only *(2 deaths from a single explosion, etc)*; consecutive kills in a single turn however grant multiple charges *(getting a kill with a free use sidearm and then with a primary weapon, etc)*.

Source: personal gameplay experience.

Comment: I’m not sure if there’s been a patch, but I was able to gain three charges in one turn in chapter 3. I used the RPG on the deployed bombs from the bomb launchers.

Comment: Do you remember your game version? I've had my experience on v2.3.2.0

Comment: Playing *SteamWold Heist: Ultimate Edition* v1.2.1 on Switch. This is the newest available version.